# Compact but open subsets in a non-Hausdorff space

Tags: general-topology

I'm working through this exercise:

> Let $S$ be the set [0,1] and define a subset $F$ of $S$ to be closed if either it is finite or is equal to $S$. Prove that this definition of closed set yields a topology for $S$. Show that $S$ with this topology is connected, path-wise connected, and compact, but that $S$ is not a Hausdorff space. Show that each subset of $S$ is compact and that therefore there are compact subsets of $S$ that are not closed.

I'm having a hard time coming up with an example that meets this definition. Once I have an example, I think I can suss out the proofs.

EDIT:

Ok. So I misunderstood 'yields a topology'--for some reason, I was thinking that you could create several different topologies using that definition, rather than just one.

I've been able to work through the connected and path-wise connected aspects, but I'm hung up on the Hausdorff space.

What's the flaw in this line of reasoning?

$a, b \in S, a < b$

$x = (a + b) / 2$

$x \in S$

$X = \{ x \}$

$X$ is a finite subset of $S$, therefore closed. $C(X)$ is open, and is therefore a member of the confinite topology on $S$.

$C(X) = [0, x), (x, 1]$

$N = [0, x); M = (x, 1]$

$N$ is a neighborhood of $a$, $M$ is a neighborhood of $b$, $N \cap M = \emptyset$, therefore this topology on $S$ is a Hausdorff space

Comment: The exercise is the example.

Comment: Is that not an example in itself? Well anyways, if your title is what you want an example of, then the trivial topology suffices if the underlying nonempty set is not a singleton

Comment: I’m trying to come up with a sample topology that meets the definition, other than the trivial topology.

Comment: @RichJensen ?? But the question gives you the topology: a subset is closed iff it is finite or equal to $S$. [In other words, the open set are $S$ itself and subsets with finite complement.]

Comment: @almagest: So, an example would be {$S$, $\emptyset$, (0,1)}, as the complement of (0,1) would be {0,1}?

Comment: @RichJensen Yes. That is an open set. In general, an open set is the interval $[0,1]$ with a finite number of points removed.(or the empty set). But, looking at your comment under the answer, a "topology" is not a specific open set. It is the collection of all the open sets.

Answer (score 3):

Read the text closely: "Show that $S$ with *this* topology (i.e. the one defined in the previous paragraph!) is connected, path-wise connected...."

Proving the fact that we have a topology on $S$ is part 1 of the exercise.

Showing the properties for this space is part 2.

This site has many solutions for them, look for [cofinite topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cofiniteness#Cofinite_topology), which is the common name.

Comment: That helps. But the main problem I was having was coming up with a specific example of a topology that matches that definition. I'm still learning, so it helps me to have a concrete example I can start from. It seems that {$S$, $\emptyset$, (0,1)} would meet the criteria. Is that correct?

Comment: @RichJensen why add $(0,1)$ as an open set ? And the exercise is for the topology where $ O \subseteq S$ is open iff $O$ is empty or of the form $S\setminus F$ with $F$ finite. No need to come up with your own example here.

Comment: For some reason or another, I was just not getting that the exercise defined only *one* topology. Having gotten past that obstacle, I made some solid progress, but I still have a question on the Hausdorff space aspect.

Comment: @RichJensen It defines a unique topology. That $[0,1]$ is not Hausdorff is an easy consequence of the fact that $[0,1]$ is not finite: any two non-empty open sets must intersect: $(S \setminus F_1) \cap (S\setminus F_2) = S\setminus (F_1 \cup F_2)$ and the last set is never empty.

Comment: Ok. I think I get it now. I was going at it from the wrong direction. If I understand this right, then, for the intersection of two non-empty open sets to be empty, their complements in [0,1] would have to have infinitely many points, but that's prohibited by the definition of the topology.

Comment: @RichJensen Yes, it's quite simple. You know exactly what the open sets are: non-empty ones are complements of finite sets. So if you have two such sets and $x$ is in neither finite complement set, it is in both open sets by definition. And there are plenty such $x$.